# Why trailing slash is cumpolsary for GET request with @path annotation

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, uri, relative-path

```
FUNCTION --1

@Path("/object/") 
public Class TestService {

@GET
@Produces({ "application/json" })
@Path("/{uid}")
public Response hello(@PathParam("uid") String uid){
    System.out.println("UID-->" + uid);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
}

=====================================================================

FUNCTION --2

@Path("/object/")
public Class TestService {

@GET
@Produces({ "application/json" })
@Path("/{uid}/")
public Response hello(@PathParam("uid") String uid){
    System.out.println("UID-->" + uid);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
}
```

When I hit: http://base-url/object/abc

Function --1 gives: UID-->null

Function --2 gives: UID-->abc

In Function --2, I just appended slash, after uid in @path. But as per documentation, it is not compulsory to add the leading slash. I don't understand why function --1 is returning null then?

Answer (score 1):

Trailing `/` in URI is optional and may be omitted. As you said is clear in [@Path documentation](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/index.html):

> For the purposes of absolutizing a path against the base URI , a leading '/' in a path is ignored and **base URIs are treated as if they ended in '/'**

In this case it seems a defect of the implementation you are using